# Android Strike Thru Text

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to strike a text from my java code in my android application, but I'm getting `Force Close`. I'm using `2.3.1` emulator, I'm using the following code to strike thru

```
TextView tvTxt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tvTxt.setPaintFlags(tvTxt.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Please help me to solve this puzzle.

Thanks in advance.

This is my Logcat

```
07-12 17:19:41.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1777): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 17:19:41.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1777): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.colors.assasin/com.colors.assasin.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 17:19:41.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
07-12 17:19:41.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
07-12 17:19:41.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-12 17:19:41.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
07-12 17:19:41.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-12 17:19:41.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-12 17:19:41.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
07-12 17:19:41.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 17:19:41.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-12 17:19:41.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-12 17:19:41.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-12 17:19:41.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 17:19:41.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1777): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 17:19:41.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at com.colors.assasin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
07-12 17:19:41.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-12 17:19:41.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
```

The `NullPointer` rising line as in `Logcat` is

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.colors.assasin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)`

is

`tvTxt.setPaintFlags(tvTxt.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);`

My `MainActivity.java` is pretty simple

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView our_text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    our_text.setPaintFlags(our_text.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

    }
}
```

The code of `activity_main.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you have some Logcat?

Comment: what is on line 27?  is tvTxt null?

Comment: the good old NPE. Show us the whole main activity class then we tell you the reason for the prob.

Comment: @Stefan Beike Please the edited post.

Comment: and I assume you have a TextView named textView1 in activity_main.xml?

Comment: @jkhouw1 Yes. I'm having it in my `activity_main.xml`

Comment: can you post your xml also ? apparently you are directing something that is missing

Comment: did you try to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: @Stefan Beike Yes I did.

Answer (score 1):

Use SpannableString to get a StrikeThrough effect.

```
private SpannableString strikeThrough(String text) {
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text);
    spannableString.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 0, text.length(), 0);
    return spannableString;
}

TextView our_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.our_text);
our_text.setText(strikeThrough((String) our_text.getText()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I don't know what is going on... but I don't want to delete this so others can see the comments.
I tested

```
TextView t=new TextView(mContext);
t.setPaintFlags(t.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

and it threw an NPE.
I changed it to

```
TextView t=new TextView(mContext);
t.setText("t");
t.setPaintFlags(t.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

and it didn't.
I changed it to

```
TextView t=new TextView(mContext);
t.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

and it didn't
and finally I changed it back to

```
TextView t=new TextView(mContext);
t.setPaintFlags(t.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

and it didn't.

You have to have paintflags set on the textview before you can do the getPaintFlags or you will get an NPE.
 so perhaps you should just use

```
our_text.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG)
```

```
if(our_text.getPaintFlags()!=null){
our_text.setPaintFlags(our_text.getPaintFlags()|Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG)
}
 else {
our_text.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG)
}
```

Comment: TextView t=new TextView(context);
t.setPaintFlags(t.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
^will give NPE
TextView t=new TextView(mContext);
t.setText("t");
t.setPaintFlags(t.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
^will not give NPE

Comment: I'm having Text in my `TextView` , Please go through my `activity_main.xml` code @jkhouw1

Comment: santhosh is sort of correct - if text is set in xml, but no flags... it gives npe.  if you set text programmatically it doesn't.  not sure what is going on with getPaintFlags() but see edited answer to test if not null before using.

Comment: `The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) int, null` @jkhouw1

Comment: @jkhouw1 really buddy don't know what's going on, but still `NPE` continues.